# Hover function interfering with a href tag

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, z-index

I have this code right here, and what I am trying to accomplish is clickable icons but it seems like the hover function I have is not allowing me to click on the icons. I have already tried z-index but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
body {
 background-image: url("background.png");
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: rgb(19,68,97)
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: inline;
}
p {
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: inline;
}
.boxAnimation {
 width: 520px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px rgba(192,192,192,1);
 -webkit-transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
 transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
 z-index: 0;
 margin: center;
}
svg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 0;
}
svg line {
 stroke-width: 6;
 stroke: #fff;
 fill: none;
 stroke-dasharray: 250;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-out;
 transition: transform .6s ease-out;
 z-index: 0;
}
div:hover {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}
div:hover svg line.top {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
 transform: translateX(-400px);
}
div:hover svg line.bottom {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
 transform: translateX(400px);
}
div:hover svg line.left {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(400px);
 transform: translateY(400px);
}
div:hover svg line.right {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px);
 transform: translateY(-400px);
}
.icons {
 z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e0037e252a.js"></script>
<body>
<center>
  <div class="boxAnimation"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1560" y2="0"/>
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="360" x2="0" y2="-720"/>
    <line class="bottom" x1="520" y1="360" x2="-1040" y2="360"/>
    <line class="right" x1="520" y1="0" x2="520" y2="1080"/>
    </svg>
    <h1>Donia Amer</h1>
    <br>
    <p>&lt; insert title &gt;</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="icons"> <a href="www.google.com"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i></a> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i> </div>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Set your `svg` `z-index: -1` instead of 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.icons` The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
**Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).**

here is the example

```css
body {
 background-image: url("background.png");
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: rgb(19,68,97)
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
 font-size: 50px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: inline;
}
p {
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: inline;
}
.boxAnimation {
 width: 520px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px rgba(192,192,192,1);
 -webkit-transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
 transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
 z-index: 0;
 margin: center;
}
svg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 0;
}
svg line {
 stroke-width: 6;
 stroke: #fff;
 fill: none;
 stroke-dasharray: 250;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-out;
 transition: transform .6s ease-out;
 z-index: 0;
}
div:hover {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}
div:hover svg line.top {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
 transform: translateX(-400px);
}
div:hover svg line.bottom {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
 transform: translateX(400px);
}
div:hover svg line.left {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(400px);
 transform: translateY(400px);
}
div:hover svg line.right {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px);
 transform: translateY(-400px);
}
.icons {
 z-index: 5;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e0037e252a.js"></script>
<body>
<center>
  <div class="boxAnimation"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1560" y2="0"/>
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="360" x2="0" y2="-720"/>
    <line class="bottom" x1="520" y1="360" x2="-1040" y2="360"/>
    <line class="right" x1="520" y1="0" x2="520" y2="1080"/>
    </svg>
    <h1>Donia Amer</h1>
    <br>
    <p>&lt; Developer + Algorithm Enthusiast &gt;</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="icons"> <a href="www.google.com"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i></a> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i> </div>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Do you mind explaining to me why that worked?

Comment: @DoniaAmer may i know why you unaccepted my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the z-index property of svg to - value

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <title>Donia Amer</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e0037e252a.js"></script>

    <style>

    body {
        background-image:url("background.png");
                background-size: 100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-color: rgb(19,68,97)

    }

    h1{

      font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
      font-size: 50px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
       display: inline;
    }

    p{
            font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
       display: inline;
    }

    .boxAnimation {
      width: 520px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px rgba(192,192,192,1);
        -webkit-transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
        transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
             z-index: 0;
            margin: center;

      }

    svg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    svg line {
      stroke-width: 6;
      stroke: #fff;
      fill: none;
      stroke-dasharray: 250;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-out;
      transition: transform .6s ease-out;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    div:hover {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

    div:hover svg line.top {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
      transform: translateX(-400px);
    }

    div:hover svg line.bottom {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
      transform: translateX(400px);
    }

    div:hover svg line.left {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(400px);
      transform: translateY(400px);
    }

    div:hover svg line.right {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px);
      transform: translateY(-400px);
    }

        .icons{
             z-index: 5;
        }

    </style>
    </head>

<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center>
    <div class="boxAnimation">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1560" y2="0"/>
        <line class="left" x1="0" y1="360" x2="0" y2="-720"/>
        <line class="bottom" x1="520" y1="360" x2="-1040" y2="360"/>
        <line class="right" x1="520" y1="0" x2="520" y2="1080"/>
            </svg>
          <h1>Donia Amer</h1><br>
          <p>&lt; Developer + Algorithm Enthusiast &gt;</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="icons">
                    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i></a>
                &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i>
                &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i>
                &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:45px;"></i>
                </div>


    </div>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is add new property in your icons selector **position:relative**

**Reminder**

z-index only works on positioned elements

**CSS**

```
.icons {
    z-index: 5;
  position:relative;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vd83vusp/)